# what's the best way to select data

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I have a game online and everything is fine, the problem is that when you login the server takes TOO LONG to select data, I use mysql and I am a newbie in it, I do not know if there is a way to optimize this or it is just slow and that's it.

this works with c# and mysql

```
        int UserId;
        DataRow dUserInfo = null;
        DataTable dAchievements = null;
        DataTable dFavouriteRooms = null;
        DataTable dIgnores = null;
        DataTable dBadges = null;
        DataTable dFriends = null;
        DataTable dRequests = null;
        DataTable dRooms = null;
        DataTable dQuests = null;
        DataTable dRelations = null;
        DataRow UserInfo = null;

        using (IQueryAdapter db = Progam.GetQueryReactor())
        {
            db.SetQuery("SELECT * " + "FROM users WHERE `auth_ticket` = @addr LIMIT 1");
            db.AddParameter("addr", SessionTicket);
            dUserInfo = db.getRow();

            UserId = Convert.ToInt32(dUserInfo["id"]);

            db.SetQuery("SELECT `group`,`level`,`progress` FROM `user_achievements` WHERE `userid` = '" + UserId + "'");
            dAchievements = db.getTable();

            db.SetQuery("SELECT room_id FROM user_favorites WHERE `user_id` = '" + UserId + "'");
            dFavouriteRooms = db.getTable();

            db.SetQuery("SELECT ignore_id FROM user_ignores WHERE `user_id` = '" + UserId + "'");
            dIgnores = db.getTable();

            db.SetQuery("SELECT `badge_id`,`badge_slot` FROM user_badges WHERE `user_id` = '" + UserId + "'");
            dBadges = db.getTable();

            db.SetQuery(
                "SELECT users.id,users.username,users.fb_name,users.motto,users.look,users.last_online,users.hide_inroom,users.hide_online " +
                "FROM users " +
                "JOIN messenger_friendships " +
                "ON users.id = messenger_friendships.user_one_id " +
                "WHERE messenger_friendships.user_two_id = " + UserId + " " +
                "UNION ALL " +
                "SELECT users.id,users.username,users.fb_name,users.motto,users.look,users.last_online,users.hide_inroom,users.hide_online " +
                "FROM users " +
                "JOIN messenger_friendships " +
                "ON users.id = messenger_friendships.user_two_id " +
                "WHERE messenger_friendships.user_one_id = " + UserId);
            dFriends = db.getTable();

            db.SetQuery("SELECT messenger_requests.from_id,messenger_requests.to_id,users.username FROM users JOIN messenger_requests ON users.id = messenger_requests.from_id WHERE messenger_requests.to_id = " + UserId);
            dRequests = db.getTable();

            db.SetQuery("SELECT * FROM rooms WHERE `user_id` = '" + UserId + "' ");
            dRooms = db.getTable();

            db.SetQuery("SELECT `q_id`,`progress` FROM user_quests WHERE `user_id` = '" + UserId + "'");
            dQuests = db.getTable();

            db.SetQuery("SELECT `id`,`user_id`,`target`,`type` FROM `user_relationships` WHERE `user_id` = '" + UserId + "'");
            dRelations = db.getTable();

            db.SetQuery("SELECT * FROM `user_info` WHERE `user_id` = '" + UserId + "' LIMIT 1");
            UserInfo = db.getRow();

            if (UserInfo == null)
            {
                db.RunQuery("INSERT INTO `user_info` (`user_id`) VALUES ('" + UserId + "')");

                db.SetQuery("SELECT * FROM `user_info` WHERE `user_id` = '" + UserId + "' LIMIT 1");
                UserInfo = db.getRow();
            }

            db.SetQuery("UPDATE `users` SET `online` = '1', `auth_ticket` = '', `machine_id` = @mid WHERE `id` = @hid LIMIT 1");
            db.AddParameter("mid", MachineId);
            db.AddParameter("hid", UserId);
            db.RunQuery();
        }
```

this take a long (10 seconds or more)

Comment: 1) I would use parameters on ALL queries, 2) you have up to 14 queries running - it's impossible to know which one(s) could be slow 3) do you have indexes on the tables? 4) add logging or run each query independently and see which ones are slow.

Comment: First, I'd take the `*` out of the first query. For all we know, without your table definitions, you could have a huge high resolution user photo blob being retrieved.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM users WHERE auth_ticket = @addr LIMIT 1` Wierd query because. SQL is a unorderd set.. Using `LIMIT 1` without `ORDER BY` MySQL wil not **always** guarantee the same record when running the query multiple times... But nothing is wrong here when auth_ticket is unique in the table... Also read about preventing SQL injection, C# does support prepared statements to protect against SQL injection

Answer (score 0):

Don't select the columns using '*'. '*' returns all the columns. If you have a lot of columns of BLOBs then it will grind to a halt since it will return those. Select the individual columns by listing them all, even if there's like a huge number.

Also, I cant  see what the responses from your server will be, however if you are only returning one row, then consider combining several queries into a single query. If you are running all those queries, then your system will do them one after another, which means you'll have a delay while the program waits for all the responses. Combine all the queries into a single query similar to below as the SQL server will get all the responses in one go and then return them.

```
SELECT
(SELECT Column1 FROM DatabaseName1 WHERE Column2 = 'Something') AS Info1,
(SELECT Column1 FROM DatabaseName2 WHERE Column2 = 'Something') AS Info2,
(SELECT Column1 FROM DatabaseName3 WHERE Column2 = 'Something') AS Info3
```

Comment: I have a feeling a lot of the OP's queries have multiple results.